# Google+ snippet generator doesn't show code

Tags: google-plus, code-snippets

Here [developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) it should be possible to generate Google+ snippet code. But it does not work, because the generated code is obscured by a div with the preview. See the screenshot made with Firefox (Chrome looks similar).

[image]

What is wrong? Is it a failure of the tool? Is there a working tool anywhere else?

Comment: upper right hand corner send  feed back its a bug i will ping google now

Comment: Thanks! I did not estimate the "feedback" link. Now I did it, but unfortunately
 the screenshot function doeas not work, the interessting area stays empty :-). Ohoh Google!